# Testing the existence of specific fields from a list

Tags: typescript, sharepoint-online, spfx

I'm trying to validate whether a list has an specific list of fields, it keeps returning all the existing fields from the list, how do I make this things work? Is there a better way to achieve what I'm trying?

```
sp.web.lists.getByTitle("SliceBox").fields.select("Title","Body","Link","Picture","Visible").get()
    .then( (fields: any[]) => {
        console.log("> number of fields returned:", fields.length);

        fields.forEach(f => {
            console.log("> field:", f);
        })              
    })
    .catch( err => {
        console.log("> fields failure: ", err);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We will have to use 'filter' in above scenario

```
 sp.web.lists.getByTitle("SliceBox").fields.filter("((Title eq 'Title') or (Title eq 'Body'))").get()
```

We can include more 'or' for more filters.
When we use 'select', it only return those selected properties within that field. Means, if we use `select('Title')` it will only return 'Title' property of all fields.

Comment: that conclusive answers my question! awesome answer and example by the way! thanks!